# Updating BizTalk Application - ApplicationNode failed

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment

I have two BizTalk applications. I updated the source code for 1 of them, checked it in TFS and it's ready to go. I've read that I have to delete the application that's currently there, so I exported msi, and bindings. The application is NOT in the control panel to remove so I went to BizTalk to delete it. I'm getting an error, Delete of ApplicationNode failed and that I have to "Remove assembly, first, it references assembly etc... " I tired to remove the assembly from Resources but it's throwing the same error.

The code change I made was a hard coded address that need updating. I have to go through all of this to update a BizTalk Application?

Comment: Is there a dependency between the two BizTalk applications?  Normally you don't need to delete applications.  Only if A is dependent on B, and you are updating B, you need to delete A first before updating B.  The other option is to do a side by side deployment by incrementing the Assmebly Version numbers of B, but then you have to update A to reference the new version as if it needs to use the new version. Only after all references to the old B have been updated can you then remove it.